# Reading Json in php using post

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm creating a JSON file using variables from my `localStorage` using this code:

```
var myObject = new Object();
    myObject.gateway = localStorage.gateway;
    myObject.qtgateway = localStorage.qtgateway;
    myObject.carte = localStorage.carte;
    myObject.qtcarte = localStorage.qtcarte;
    myObject.capt = localStorage.capt;
    myObject.qtcapt = localStorage.qtcapt;
    myObject.act = localStorage.act;
    myObject.qtact = localStorage.qtact;
    myObject.conn = localStorage.conn;
    myObject.qtconn = localStorage.qtconn;

r = JSON.stringify(myObject);
$.post("http://localhost/argon-dashboard-master/api/rapport/", {data: r});
```

But I don't know how to receive my JSON in the PHP file `index.php`.

Comment: Where are you getting stuck? See [$_POST](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: formatting, remove unnecessary "excuse" cruft

Comment: Did you try `file_get_contents()` and `json_decode()`? Here was my first result from a search "read JSON file in index.php file":  https://www.codewall.co.uk/how-to-read-json-file-using-php-examples/. Does that help answer your question? (thinking up good search phrases is half the battle).  Please also read [how to ask a question on SO](https:stackOverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then `edit` to provide enough detail that we can help with your issue. Be sure to click on the embedded link on "Minimum Viable Examples".

Comment: It worked i used $x=$_POST;
$x=json_decode($x["data"], true);